# How can I convert a string of MMMYYYY to a date in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm looking to get records that are over a year old but unfortunately they only have date strings like `JAN2019`. I need to some how convert this to a `DATETIME` of 1/1/2019 to be able get records less than `SYSDATE-365`.

I can use `SUBSTR` to get the month and year but I don't know how to convert the string value of the month into a numeric value in order to convert or cast it into a date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TO_DATE` would help, I presume.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = english;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set nls_date_Format = 'dd/mm/yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select to_date('JAN2019', 'monyyyy') from dual;

TO_DATE('J
----------
01/01/2019

SQL>
```

(You most probably don't need `alter session` commands; I do, because my database speaks *Croatian* and uses different date format so I just tried to make it look closer to what you use).

Comment: Or you could use the optional third parameter to set the date language (e.g.`to_date('JAN2019', 'MONyyyy', 'nls_date_language=english')) - which you should be using if your date-as-strings contain words from a particular language. That way, it doesn't matter what the database or client NLS settings are, the conversion to date will always work.

Comment: looks like this is going to work where TO_DATE(a.conmonth,'MONyyyy') < sysdate - 365

Comment: Just pay attention to leap years. ADD_MONTHS might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TO_DATE(('01'||'JAN2019'),'dd/mm/yyyy') AS new_date_format FROM table_name;
```

*Remark:*

you can change `'JAN2019'` into column_name